# In Android, a possible black screen may occur as switching activity

Tags: android, lifecycle

I did some experiments on investigating Activity switching life cycle, and found there's a situation a "black screen" will occur. If I'm wrong please kindly correct me.

Two Activities A & B. Launch to B from A.

```
03-06 13:04:52.811: I/LOG(32125): pause A begin
03-06 13:04:53.811: I/LOG(32125): pause A return
03-06 13:04:53.813: I/LOG(32125): focus A begin
03-06 13:04:58.813: I/LOG(32125): focus A return

In the window, shows the view of Activity A.

03-06 13:04:58.829: I/LOG(32125): create B begin
03-06 13:04:58.845: I/LOG(32125): create B return
03-06 13:04:58.846: I/LOG(32125): start B begin
03-06 13:04:59.847: I/LOG(32125): start B return

The view of Act A is hide, it is now shown by Activity B, but it's actually a "black screen" rather than the "actual genereated layout" in Activity B

03-06 13:04:59.847: I/LOG(32125): resume B begin
03-06 13:05:00.847: I/LOG(32125): resume B return
03-06 13:05:00.968: I/LOG(32125): focus B begin
03-06 13:05:05.968: I/LOG(32125): focus B return

Until this point, the "actual generated layout" of Activity B is shown here.

03-06 13:05:06.044: I/LOG(32125): A onSaveInstance
03-06 13:05:06.044: I/LOG(32125): stop A begin
03-06 13:05:07.044: I/LOG(32125): stop A return
```

Below is the code in my Activity A & B. I use Thread.sleep to simulate the long period task. ( Maybe this is not an appropriate way make the simulation? )

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("LOG","start B begin");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000,0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("LOG","start B return");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("LOG","resume B begin");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000,0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("LOG","resume B return");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("LOG","stop B begin");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000,0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("LOG","stop B return");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("LOG", "pause B begin");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000,0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("LOG","pause B return");
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.i("LOG","focus B begin");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000,0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("LOG","focus B return");
}
```

From above experiments, I came up with some conclusion and design strategies.

1. Don't do too much things on Act B onResume & onFocus, or else users will see "black screen".
2. Following by (1), do it in Act B "onStart" in instead. It's better to let user feel the delay with there's a view shown by previous Act A than seeing a "black screen".
3. AsyncTask is definitely the solution. Show the view to user is top priority, data applied afterward.

---

However, there's also a scenario like this: 
A chart application. User see the "chart(layout)" in the Activity, but the latest data hasn't filled in yet because the second thread is still fetching the data (maybe because it's too heavy).

User will see a blank chart at this point. To avoid this, we can then get the data prior to the creation of Activity. Either do this in the previous Activity or in the beginning of Application. To smooth the user experience.

---

Did any one find this "black screen" pitfall as well? Or did I understand things incorrectly? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show code what you have in activity A and B

Answer (score 0):

You stumbled at one of the base principles with android:

> Don't do (too much) work on the main thread.

The main thread is your UI thread. Lifecycle callback methods like `onCreate`, `onStart` and so on are all called on the main / UI thread.

If you do too much work, you will end up with the screen freezing and / or black screens, yes.

This should not however influence where you would create your views or fill them with data. This is why there are different lifecycle methods. E.g. `onCreate` is called once, which is why you should set your layout there. Doing things `onResume` will called every time the user switches back to your activity, e.g. you should resume animations there.

`AsyncTask` is indeed a good idea for loading data off the main thread. If you want to properly do it, also have a look at `LoaderManager` and `Loader` in general.

5 seconds to execute lifecycle callbacks should *not* be the case. Use loaders that you start in `onCreate` or some other place appropriate and fill your views with data when they finish. Make sure you understand when each lifecycle callback is called, because doing the same thing multiple times (e.g. `onResume`) could also be wasted energy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding sleeps in all of your code above will hang the main thread (which is the ui thread) - that could explain the weird black screens. What if there weren't any sleeps there? I think you can still learn about the lifecycle through the logs but without any sleeps.

I understand that you're making a simulation, but if your actual tasks are going to take that long, do explore multi-threading methods (keywords: Looper, AsyncTask, Thread, Runnable, Message, Queue, Post, Handlers etc... it's a complex topic).